# Ubuntu 13.10 (32bit) on acer aspire one

Tags: acer, ram

Has anyone ever tried Ubuntu (32bit) on an acer aspire one d255 2dqkk with 1GB of Ram or 2GB?
At the moment I have 1GB installed and I would like to add 1GB more.

Answer (score 1):

A 32 Bit operating system will handle 2GB of Ram just fine.
But you should consider upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 or use 12.04, since 13.10 is no longer supported.

Comment: And would 14.04 version work fine with this laptop?

Comment: Yes 14.04 should run just fine.

Comment: But.. Did you try?

Comment: No I don't own the laptop. But if 13.10 runs just fine there is no reason why 14.04 should not work.

Comment: Yeah... I now but my pc sucks

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com) is a **lightweight** but powerful operating system needs ***at least 512MB of random access memory*** to start operating, so 1GB ram will work just fine. On top of that, a 32Bit architecture is also lightweight and runs on most machines, even ancient ones.. So it will work just fine on your [Acer](http://www.acer.com) laptop